# How to turn this code into loop to simplify it?

Tags: php, loops

How can I simplify this code as a loop? Do i need to use a `foreach` loop inside the loop too?

```
foreach ($data as $item) {
    $a = new stdClass;
    $a->v = $item->location_name;
    $a->f = null;

    $b = new stdClass;
    $b->v = intval($item->count);
    $b->f = null;

    $c = new stdClass;
    $c->c = array($a, $b);

    $rows[] = $c;
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: i don't know how to simplify it..

Comment: I think this questions would be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could more simply use `array_map` and some array-to-object casting

```
$rows = array_map(function($item) {
    return (object) ['c' => [
        (object) ['v' => $item->location_name, 'f' => null],
        (object) ['v' => intval($item->count), 'f' => null]
    ]];
}, array_values($data));
```

Comment: thanks @phill....your solution output this one:"rows":{"2":[{"c":[{"v":"Kedah","f":null},  almost right. but i need the output to be like this: "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Johor","f":null}.  i tried to alter but still not achieve the right output..

Comment: @jun I assumed `$data` was a plain array. Try using `array_values($data)` instead of just `$data`

Comment: thanks @Phil, it works perfectly. Thank you for the solutions..can you explain a little bit on array_values function if you don't mind, i'm a beginner in php

Comment: @jun sure. Seems your `$data` array had some non-continuous keys that were being interpreted as strings, hence the "2". `array_values` just returns the values from an array as a standard, zero-based,  integer indexed array